# Prove a polynomial sequence converges to infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

Let’s assume $p$ is a positive integer and $x_n$ is a sequence equal to

$c_0 + c_1 n + ... + c_p n^p$

where all $c_m$s are real numbers and $c_p$ is not zero.

How should we prove that:

A) $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n| = +\infty$

B) If $c_p < 0$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = -\infty$

Comment: Use your common sense intuition. Which terms are (comparatively) large, which are small? Turn that into a mathematical argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$c_0+....+c_pn^p=c_pn^p(1+\frac{c_{p-1}}{c_pn}+...+\frac{1}{c_pn^p})$$

Now if $c_p>0$ then  $\lim_na_n=+\infty$

If $c_p<0$ then $\lim_n a_n=-\infty$

And $|a_n|=|c_pn^p||(1+\frac{c_{p-1}}{c_pn}+...+\frac{1}{c_pn^p})|$

So $\lim_n|a_n|=+\infty$

Answer (score 1):

$f(n)
=\sum_{j=0}^p c_j n^j
=c_pn^p+\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}c_j n^{j})
$
so
$f(n)-c_pn^p
=n^p\sum_{j=0}^{p-1} c_j n^{j-p}
$
or
$\dfrac{f(n)}{n^p}-c_p
=\sum_{j=0}^{p-1} c_j n^{j-p}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
|\dfrac{f(n)}{n^p}-c_p|
&\le |\sum_{j=0}^{p-1} c_j n^{j-p}|\\
&\le \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} |c_j n^{j-p}|\\
&\le \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} |c_j| n^{j-p}\\
&\le \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} |c_j| n^{-1}\\
&=\dfrac1{n} \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} |c_j|\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if
$\dfrac1{n} \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} |c_j|
\lt |c_p/2|$,
or
$n\gt |\dfrac{2}{c_p}| \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} |c_j|
$,
we have
$|\dfrac{f(n)}{n^p}-c_p|
\ge |c_p/2|$
so that
$|\dfrac{f(n)}{n^p}|
\ge |c_p/2|$
or
$|f(n)|
\ge |c_p/2|n^p
$
and
$f(n)$
has the same sign as
$c_p$.